# g++ can't find the libraries despite include and lib specification

Tags: makefile, compilation, g++

i was trying to build my sfml program, so i wrote this makefile:

```
SFML = /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1
JSONCPP =  /usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1
INCFOLDER = -I ${SFML}/include -I ${JSONCPP}/include
LIBFOLDER = -L ${SFML}/lib -L ${JSONCPP}/lib
CC = g++ 
STD = -std=c++11
ALIAS =  -o sfml

LIBS =  -l libsfml-audio.2.5.1.dylib -l libsfml-graphics.2.5.1.dylib  -l libsfml-network.2.5.1.dylib -llibsfml-system.2.5.1.dylib  -l libsfml-window.2.5.1.dylib 
LIBS+= -l jsoncpp.24.dylib
MAIN = main.cpp

exe:
    ${CC} ${MAIN} ${INCFOLDER} ${LIBFOLDER} ${LIBS} ${ALIAS} ${STD}
```

I'm on mac and i installed these libraries via brew, so they are installed in /usr/local/cellar.
I specified the include folder with -I, the lib folder with -L then the single libraries whose names i copy-pasted in place.
What's wrong with this make file? I can't understand...
This is the error:

```
g++  main.cpp -I /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/include -I 

/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/include -L /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib -L /usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib -l libsfml-audio.2.5.1.dylib -l libsfml-graphics.2.5.1.dylib  -l libsfml-network.2.5.1.dylib -llibsfml-system.2.5.1.dylib  -l libsfml-window.2.5.1.dylib  -l jsoncpp.24.dylib -o sfml -std=c++11
ld: library not found for -llibsfml-audio.2.5.1.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

Comment: In general, the option `-lfoo` will try to link with `libfoo.dylib`.  So try `-l  libsfml-audio.2.5.1.dylib` --> `-lsfml-audio.2.5.1` etc.  You may not need the version numbers either depending on exactly what was installed.

Comment: I erased lib and .dylib from each library and now i goes well, but i can swear that in the past i used the same method on this same library and it compiled, any idea why that is?

Comment: You can either use `libfoo.dylib` (or `libfoo.a` on traditional UNIX systems) without the `-l` option, or you can use `-lfoo` without the `lib` and suffix.  It's never worked, anywhere, to use both the `-l` and the `lib` and suffix at the same time.  So if you're remembering doing that successfully then your memory is faulty :)